# PHP Array input name to database

Tags: php, arrays

I am working on a hotel feature page.

the peice of code I am stuck on is the following:

```
<?php 
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from facilities_type");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
?>
 <tr>
    <th scope="row">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="blankCheckbox" name="room_feature_cb[]" value="<?php echo $row["facilitiestype_id"]; ?>">
    </th>
    <td>
        <?php echo $row["room_facilities"] ?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <img src="upload-img/icon/<?php echo $row["facilities_icon"]; ?>" width="25">
    </td>
 </tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

I want to save the data by using the array, but i cannot get the name to save into the database

```
if (isset($_POST["room_feature_savebtn"])) 
{
    $feature = $_POST['room_feature_cb'];
    for($result=0;$result>$feature;$result++)
    {
    mysqli_query($conn,"insert into facilities_details(facilitiestype_id) value ('$feature')");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `foreach`, is a better option in this case:

```
if (isset($_POST["room_feature_savebtn"])) 
{
    $features = $_POST['room_feature_cb'];
    foreach ($features as $feature) {
        mysqli_query($conn, "insert into facilities_details(facilitiestype_id) value ('$feature')");
    }
}
```

Your error is when make a `for` you dont use the index of array (`$result`) that create in this, try with:

```
if (isset($_POST["room_feature_savebtn"])) 
{
    $feature = $_POST['room_feature_cb'];
    for($result=0; $result < $feature; $result++)   {
        mysqli_query(
            $conn,
            "insert into facilities_details(facilitiestype_id) value ('" . $feature[$result] . "')"
        );
    }
```

}

I recomend the `foreach`